# connect to smb share with root access

Tags: samba, samba4, smb-conf

Ok, I have smb configured on my Centos 6.7 environment, I have added the user root with smbpasswd -a and when I browse to the share from my windows box I connect with the samba root user I created a password for, but I don't have linux root permissions when I click on the directories. As you can see below, I want to have access to /. Here is the config:

```
[Daze]
comment = Default connect
path = /
valid users = admin root 
force user = root
force group = root
browsable = yes
admin users = root, root
public = yes
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
read only = No
directory mode = 0777
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This is a unwise, which is why there are votes to close the question. Opening Samba write access to the root partition is a significant security risk.  It is certainly possible, and if you google samba share root partition should get your answer.

Comment: It is not unwise if it's in a properly secured local network.

Answer (score 4):

Arguments for the `valid users` parameter must be comma-separated. Also, notice that you typed "writable" instead of `writeable`. And, because `writeable` is the inverted synonym of `read only`, there's no need to declare the `read only` parameter.

Here's the correct config:

```
[Daze]
comment = Default connect
path = /
valid users = admin, root 
force user = root
force group = root
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
admin users = root
public = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

Restart your Samba server (run e.g. `sudo service smbd restart` or `sudo systemctl restart smbd.service`) with these configs and see if it works.

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't work for my uses
Any other ideas? [Daze]
comment = Default connect
path = /
valid users = admin, root force user = root
force group = root
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
admin users = root
public = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777

Comment: @VickyPenny Try setting your shared folder in your `smb.conf` file with these parameters (replace each **;** character with a **line break** and don't forget to restart the Samba server after saving the changes you did in your `smb.conf` file):
`[Shared];path = /;comment = My shared folder;admin users = root;available = yes;browseable = yes;create mask = 0777;directory mask = 0777;force group = root;force user = root;guest ok = no;locking = yes;printable = no;public = yes;root = /;strict locking = no;valid users = root;writeable = yes;write list = root`

Comment: With out knowing what config file we are editing this information is useless to a newbie.

Comment: @wheredidthatnamecomefrom The question was made / presented under the premise that the user alreay has "smb configured" (sic) on its Linux "environment", which implies that such user isn't a newbie (or is, but yet knows where the config file is located and what its structure is). Anyway: on most Linux distributions (CentOS Linux included), the Samba config file is `smb.conf` and its located at `/etc/samba/`. If `updatedb` is available on the Linux distribution, running `sudo updatedb` and then `locate -i smb.conf` provides the current location of all `smb.conf` files on such Linux system.